# Remove Ellipse from Table Output

Tags: powershell

I am trying to output to a text file the results of the powershell cmdlet `Compare-Object` The problem is I cannot eliminate the ellipse truncation.

The code below provides a table formatting definition variable which specifies a width of 1000 for the Path column.  Yet the output file always truncates the Path column at 122 characters.

The `Compare-Object` cmdlet is comparing two ArrayLists which are just lists of file path strings from common folder paths between two servers.

What I am attempting to do is put the SideIndicator as the first column and the full path in the second. I do not want truncating of the file path.

```
$tableFormat = @{Expression={$_.SideIndicator};Label="Side Indicator";width=15}, @{Expression={$_.InputObject};Label="Path";width=1000} 
$outputFilename = ($server1 + "_" + $server2 + "_FileCompare" + ".txt");
Compare-Object $Hive1FileArray $Hive2FileArray -IncludeEqual | Format-Table $tableFormat | Out-String | Out-File $outputFilename
```

[image]

I also tried removing `Out-String` from the pipe makes no difference.

What is going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Compare-Object $Hive1FileArray $Hive2FileArray -IncludeEqual |`
     Format-Table $tableFormat -AutoSize |`
        Out-String -Width 1000 |`
            Out-File $outputFilename
```

Read

- `Get-Help 'Format-Table' -ShowWindow` or its [Online Version](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=293962):

> ```
> -AutoSize
> ```
>
> Adjusts the column size and number of columns based on the width of
>   the data. By default, the column size and number are determined by the
>   view.

- `Get-Help 'Out-String' -ShowWindow` or its [Online Version](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=293999):

> ```
> -Width <Int32>
> ```
>
> Specifies the number of characters in each line of output. **Any
>   additional characters are truncated**, not wrapped. If you omit this
>   parameter, the width is determined by the characteristics of the host
>   program. The default value for the Windows PowerShell console is 80
>   (characters).

Not much more to say not knowing `Compare-Object` cmdlet input objects…

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year old but another useful parameter of Format-Table is -wrap.

-Wrap []
        Indicates that the cmdlet displays text that exceeds the column width on the next line. By default, text that exceeds the column width is truncated.

```
    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                False
    Accept pipeline input?       False
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```