# Powershell length won't show up in output of Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

I'm trying this command in Windows 10 PowerShell:

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select FullName,Length,LastAccessTime`

The result only contains `FullName` , while `LastAccessTime` and `Length` is missing from output.

[PowerShell ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwqDm.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The same command works for me (tested on versions 5 and 7). Maybe the output is just offscreen somewhere.

Comment: I wrote the output to a file using ```Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select FullName,Length,LastAccessTime | Out-File list.txt ```. It's only shows filenames. Also tried  using Format Table but still nothing

Comment: Try: `... | Format-Table -Property @{expression='ps*'; width=10}`

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36516106/3439404): `…| Out-String -Width 1000 | Out-File list.txt`

Comment: What if you put fullname last

Comment: it returns empty output

Comment: Instead of Out-File, use `Export-Csv` or output the objects using `Out-GridView`

Comment: What if you use the actual `Select-Object` cmdlet (instead of its alias) or just: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Format-Table FullName,Length,LastAccessTime`?

Comment: 'Export-Csv' solutions works. @iRon I think, the problem is due to length of filenames. Thanks for the help Guys.

Comment: which is why putting it last should've shown all 3, with fullname cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select FullName,Length,LastAccessTime | Export-Csv list.csv`

Answer (score 3):

**The problem is merely a *display* problem:**

- Because the paths among the output objects are long and `FullName` is the *first* property selected, the **remaining properties (columns) don't *print*, because they cannot fit on the screen.** However, the properties *are* present, and can be used programmatically.
- Note: **If the intent is to save *to a file* for later *programmatic processing***, you shouldn't  use `>` / `Out-File`, which result in the same *for-display* formatting that you see in the console (terminal), because this formatting is meant only for the *human observer*.

  - For *programmatic processing*, **use a *structured data format* such as CSV**, as shown in [Ashok Prasath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65382203/45375)

---

**Workarounds**:

- A quick-and-dirty workaround is to **put the `FullName` property *last***, as [Doug Maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer) advises, which will make *all* properties (columns) show, though the `FullName` property values will be *truncated* (symbolized with `…`), and notably from the *start* of the paths:

  ```
  # FullName is placed *last*
  # Caveat: Paths will be truncated at the *end*.
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select Length, LastAccessTime, FullName
  ```
- If you don't mind **switching to a *list*-based format**, where each property value is represented on its own line prefixed by the property name, pipe to [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list); note that overly long values will *line-wrap*:

  ```
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select FullName,Length,LastAccessTime | Format-List
  ```
- If you do want *tabular* output and don't mind ***line-wrapping* in your output**, you can pipe to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) with a `-Width` value large enough to fit all columns (note that [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) also supports `-Width`):

  ```
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select FullName,Length,LastAccessTime |
    Out-String -Width 300
  ```

  - **If you prefer horizontal scrolling** to line wrapping, you could save the above to a file and **open in it a text editor** or, with a text editor such as [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), you can directly *pipe* the output to it:

    ```
    # Opens the output directly in a new Visual Studio Code editor tab.
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select FullName,Length,LastAccessTime |
      Out-String -Width 300 | code -
    ```
- Otherwise - **if you do want to see *tabular* display *in the console*, in the *exact column order specified* and *without line-wrapping* - your only option is to *truncate* the `FullName` values** so that all columns can fit; note that, for brevity, I am omitting the `select` ([`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)) call in favor of direct use of [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table):

  ```
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Format-Table @{ e='FullName'; w=[Console]::WindowWidth-45; a='right'},
                 Length, LastAccessTime
  ```

  - Note how the column width (`w` entry, short for `width`) is based on the console window's with (`[Console]::WindowWidth`) minus `45` characters, to show as much of the `FullName` values as possible while still leaving room for the other two columns; also, to ensure that truncation (symbolized with `…` is applied to the *start* of the path - so that file/directory *name* is always displayed - the column is right-aligned (via the `a` entry, short for `alignment`); if you prefer truncation of the *end* of the path, *omit* the `a` entry (which then defaults to `left`).
  - For more information on this hashtable-based (`@{ ... }`) way of specifying so-called [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) for `Format-Table`, including a way to truncate from the *start* while also maintaining *left* alignment, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38576389/45375).